# Microsoft Excel Concatenation #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, concatenation, valueerror

To try and make an everyday task for myself easier, I've been attempting to use:

`=CONCATENATE(A1:A9)`

Basically I have to grab groups of cells and wrap the text to fit in an attribute box elsewhere. I figured doing it right in Excel would be easier than writing something original with, say, Python, but I'm not having any luck. I get that vague `#VALUE!` error when entering this. Additionally, there shouldn't be any delimiter. The goal is to tie each cell end to end, wrapping it, without spaces, like I mentioned above.

For clarification, I'm using Excel 2016.

Does anybody have a remedy?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: You cannot use `concatenate` like that, you need to click on the cells one by one: `concatenate(A1,A2,A3...)`

Comment: If you're open to VBA, there would be a solution that way if it's worth your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 2016 or 365, use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, A1:A9)
```

The **" "** means that your values will be delimited by spaces (put a comma or dash or whatever you need in there); the **TRUE** means that it will not include empty cells (change it to **FALSE** if you want placeholders for those); **A1:A9** is your range that will be concatenated.

Answer (score 3):

`CONCATENATE(A1:A9)` accomplishes nothing. It just returns `A1:A9`.

I assume you want this:

```
= CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3,...A9)
```

Or:

```
= A1&A2&A3&...&A9
```

Possibly also `TEXTJOIN` if you have the right version of Excel.

Comment: Instead of `TEXTJOIN`,`CONCAT` would be better in this situation as the OP does not want a deliminator. `=CONCAT(A1:A9)` but like TEXTJOIN it needs Office 365 Excel.